# How to query two from two seperate datatables with different values

Tags: mysql

How would I query the following?

```
User.name and Groups.description, 
from the User table and Groups table, 
where User.id_user = User_Group.id_user, and Groups.id_groups = User_Group.id_groups
```

I read about `UNION` and `Join`s, but `UNION` requires the tables to have the same number of columns, while the `JOIN`s seem to work only with 2 tables?? Is it possible to combine `UNION` and `Join`s?

```
SELECT User.Name
FROM User
FULL JOIN User_Groups
ON User.Id_user= User_Groups.Id_user
UNION
SELECT Group.Description
FROM Group
FULL JOIN User_Groups
ON Group.Id_group= Groups.Id_group
```

Would the above code be right??

Comment: What is your expected output ? a single column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this simplified query:

```
SELECT u.Name
FROM   User u
JOIN   User_Groups USING (Id_user)

UNION  ALL
SELECT g.Description
FROM   Group g
JOIN   User_Groups USING (Id_group)
```

- Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`, because `UNION` would eliminate any rows with the same values.
- The result of a `UNION` has only one header, the column names are taken from the fist `SELECT` in the query. So the column name will be "Name" in your case.
- `USING` is just a syntactical simplification for `ON` when the joining columns share the same name(s)  and occur only once left and right of the join.
- Table aliases `User AS u` or simply `User u` simplify later references in the code.
- You can `JOIN` as many tables as you like, this is not limited to two tables. I suspect, what you really want is this:

```
SELECT u.Name, g.Description
FROM   User u
JOIN   User_Groups USING (Id_user)
JOIN   Group g USING (Id_group)
```

- But there is no `FULL [OUTER] JOIN` in MySQL. Other RDBMS have that, like PostgreSQL. [Read here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-select.html).
  I suspect, that's not what you wanted to begin with and replaced it with a plain `[INNER] JOIN`. Read [more in the manual here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html).

Comment: We read the question differently (i read many to many relationship)!! i assumed the OP wanted 2 columns and was just confused about the UNION syntax ?!?!?!

Comment: +1 im quite new to using MySQL - using SO to learn more complex queries (like joins) - just discovered USING from your answer - so if nothing else you taught me something !!!!

Comment: @ManseUK: I only just now saw your comment, but I concur with your interpretation - n:m relationship - as you can see from the added parts of my answer.

Comment: HUmm okay I tried that query, and I got the following error: Caused by: br.dao.DAOExceptions: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id_user' not found. Why would the colum for id_user not found, when both my tables, User_Group and User has the column, id_user?

Comment: Well I User_Group is a associative entity, having a many to 1 relationship with User, and many to 1 relationship with Group. The User_Group table has Id_user and Id_group as a Primary Composite Key. I want the User_Group table to display two columns of data (name from User, description from Group) by Ids

Comment: @ShaunK: Check your spelling ... and read about [case sensitivity here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html). You write `User_Group` here, but `User_Groups` in your question ...

Comment: OKay I got it fixed! Thanks Erwin!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this also,  I think, no need of join.

```
SELECT u.name, g.description FROM User u, Groups g, User_Group ug, Groups.id gi 
WHERE u.id_user=g.id_user and g.id_groups=ug.id_groups;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
SELECT User.Name, Groups.Description
FROM User
JOIN User_Group on User.id_user = User_Group.id_user
JOIN Groups on Groups.id_groups = User_Group.id_groups
```

or

```
SELECT User.Name, Groups.Description
FROM User
JOIN User_Group USING (id_user)
JOIN Groups USING (id_groups)
```

Not sure why you want to use the `union` for ? (unless you want 1 column - which you didnt specify)